# How to find the parametric equation of: $x^2-3y^2=1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, parametric

**Question**

How to find the parametric equation of: $x^2-3y^2=1$

I know that $x=\cos{\theta}$ and $x=\sin{\theta}$

But I've come up with the bogus solution that the answer is:

$\cos{\theta}^2-3(\sin{\theta})^2=1$

I was wondering what was the real way in parametricizing this equation?

Comment: Try $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write
$$x^2-3y^2=1$$
$$x^2-(\sqrt{3}y)^2=1$$
compare with
$$\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$$
so we have
\begin{cases}
x=\cosh t\\
\sqrt{3}y=\sinh t
\end{cases}
or
\begin{cases}
x=\cosh t\\
y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sinh t
\end{cases}

Comment: But doesn't $cosht$ only have positive numbers for all real numbers t? $x^2-3y^2=1$ also has points where x is negative.

Answer (score 4):

What about $$x=\sec t,\quad y=\frac{\tan t}{\sqrt{3}}\;\LARGE ?$$